# What happens when I decide to improve an edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

As I've been reviewing suggested edits a couple times I chose to improve the edit because the original editor made good suggestions but I found a few more things that could be fixed.

Does that user still earn +2 reputation if other users accepted this edit? Does the edit go in automatically because I have that privilege?

Answer (score 7):

The edit gets automatically approved by the community user.

The editor gets the 2 points but their edit never actually becomes visible except in the revision history as the approval is instantly superseded by your edit.

Comment: So does their initial edit still need to be approved by (three?) other users? Or does my improvement just automatically accept their edit?

Comment: Your improvement automatically accepts the edit irrespective of any other votes. If you don't want that to happen then choose "reject and edit"

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I forgot that button was there also.